# Do Bootstrap 5 dropdowns need the additional outer div?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I've spent considerable time struggling with an issue with Bootstrap 5 dropdowns. The issue is where the dropdown is clipped by the containing table and/or `table-responsive` div, and the `data-boundary="viewport"` that worked in Bootstrap 4 no longer works.

[image: Dropdown clipped by container]

Finally, I found that adding the `position-static` class solved the issue.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">#</th>
        <th scope="col">First</th>
        <th scope="col">Last</th>
        <th scope="col">Handle</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">1</th>
        <td>
          <div class="dropdown position-static">
            <span type="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown">
              <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/80x20" title="Menu" />
            </span>
            <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
              <a asp-page="AddBol" class="dropdown-item">Manual Entry</a>
              <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
              <a asp-page="AddBol" class="dropdown-item">Manual Entry</a>
              <a asp-page="AddBol" class="dropdown-item">Manual Entry</a>
              <a asp-page="AddBol" class="dropdown-item">Manual Entry</a>
              <a asp-page="AddBol" class="dropdown-item">Manual Entry</a>
              <a asp-page="AddBol" class="dropdown-item">Manual Entry</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td>Otto</td>
        <td>@mdo</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">2</th>
        <td>Jacob</td>
        <td>Thornton</td>
        <td>@fat</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">3</th>
        <td colspan="2">Larry the Bird</td>
        <td>@twitter</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

But then I continued to play with this and I found that it also worked if I removed the outer `dropdown` div and instead gave that class to the dropdown button.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">#</th>
        <th scope="col">First</th>
        <th scope="col">Last</th>
        <th scope="col">Handle</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">1</th>
        <td>
          <span type="button" class="dropdown" data-bs-toggle="dropdown">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/80x20" title="Menu" />
          </span>
          <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
            <a asp-page="AddBol" class="dropdown-item">Manual Entry</a>
            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
            <a asp-page="AddBol" class="dropdown-item">Manual Entry</a>
            <a asp-page="AddBol" class="dropdown-item">Manual Entry</a>
            <a asp-page="AddBol" class="dropdown-item">Manual Entry</a>
            <a asp-page="AddBol" class="dropdown-item">Manual Entry</a>
            <a asp-page="AddBol" class="dropdown-item">Manual Entry</a>
          </div>

        </td>
        <td>Otto</td>
        <td>@mdo</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">2</th>
        <td>Jacob</td>
        <td>Thornton</td>
        <td>@fat</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">3</th>
        <td colspan="2">Larry the Bird</td>
        <td>@twitter</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

This is not how the Bootstrap documentation says to make a dropdown. All their [examples](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/dropdowns) include that outer div.

The version without the outer div seems to work fine in all cases for me. Does anyone know what the outer div is for, or what kind of problems one might have from using this simplified structure?

Comment: What is `span type="button"`? Spans don't have a type. For accessibility, use `role="button"`.

Comment: Funny that [this problem goes way back to version 3](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/15374) and the Bootstrap team still haven't dealt with it. Your static solution seems like it's the ticket.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In looking at the styles on the outer div we see that the only rule is `position: relative;`. Presumably this is to facilitate the absolute positioning of the dropdown child element.

Whether you need that is up to you.

Comment: Thanks but I don't understand why you changed my markup when you added the ability to run my code snippets.

Comment: I [changed](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72620615/revisions) three things: Tables were added per your description, the image path was replaced with a placeholder, and Bootstrap assets were loaded via CDN to make it all work. Which was a problem?

Comment: Of course, you're always free to revise further. I only did what I thought should've been done in the first place, so we could see the problem clearly.